# Expectation of log of linear combination of Normal RVs

Tags: logarithms, normal-distribution, expected-value

Let $g \in \mathbb{R}^K$ be a vector of constants and let $x \in \mathbb{R}^K$ be a vector of Normal random variables with some means and variances. What is $E[\text{log}(g^Tx)]$? 
$$
E[\text{log}(g^Tx)]=\int\text{log}(g^Tx)f(g^Tx)dg^Tx
$$

To proceed I need to know the distribution function of $g^Tx$. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Equivalent_definitions) states that $g^Tx$ should be a univariate normal distribution with zero variance and a point mass on the mean, but I don't understand why that is.

Any insights would be appreciated! Or if there's a more straightforward way than the definition of the expectation.

Edit: as Estacionario points out, this is not well defined when x is negative. I have the additional constraint that $x$ is actually a truncated normal distribution with support only over $[0,1]$. For example, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution and set a=0 and b=1.

Comment: Wikipedia states that $g^Tx$ must be a univariate normal distribution *where in the case it has* zero variance then it is a point mass on the mean value. This is just to cover a specific degenerate case but it is not the general case.

Comment: Oh duh. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Anyway, computing that expectation analytically will probably be impractical. Numerical methods are quite straightforward given the distribution of $Y=g^Tx$. If you know the density of $Y=g^Tx$ as $f_Y(y)$ then you can approximate $\int \log y f_Y(y)dy$ via e.g. trapezoid rule. Alternatively use Monte Carlo methods: simulate a large number of $Y_i$ and compute the sample mean of $\log Y_i$. Of course this latter technique is now subject to uncertainty errors (which can be reasoned about via the CLT) as well as numerical errors.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the expectation is well defined here. The linear combination of normal random variables $g^T x$ is itself normally distributed and hence can take negative values, of which you can't then take the logarithm.

Comment: This is a good point. Actually, in my problem, x is constrained between 0 and 1 with point masses on 0 and 1 to ensure it is a proper distribution.

Comment: Do you mean that each element of x has zero variance?

Comment: @ohblahitsme Can you make its distribution precise? "Gaussian except bound with masses at the ends" isn't enough detail.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution where a=0 and b=1